# How to get the data from mongodb using node.js andfront-end as angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am currently learning node.js and creating test application using angular so in that i need to retrieve data stored in Mongodb below i have written query to get mongodb data using node.js but unable to get data so what is the exact procedure for changes need to be done in query.

In Html(component in angular):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="container">
  <table class="table mar-top-20">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Client Name</th>
  <th>Client Email</th>
  <th>Client Password</th>
  <th>Action/Status</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>{{userDetails.added_on}}</td>
  <td>{{userDetails.username}}</td>
  <td>{{userDetails.uemail}}</td>
  <td>{{userDetails.upassword}}</td>
  <td>Show Detail</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

In TS file(component in angular):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup , Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data.service';
import { AccountService } from '../../../services/account.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
// import { Client } from '../../../client';

@Component({
selector: 'app-manage-users',
templateUrl: './manage-users.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./manage-users.component.css'],

})
export class ManageUsersComponent implements OnInit {
  userDetails: any;

rForm: FormGroup;
post:any;
username: String = '';
uemail: String = '';
upassword: String = '';

constructor(private router: Router,private fb:FormBuilder,private dataService: DataService, private accountService: AccountService) {
this.rForm = fb.group({
'username':['', Validators.required],
'uemail':['', Validators.required],
'upassword': [ '', Validators.required ]
});
}

ngOnInit() {
//Getting user using userId
this.accountService.getUser({ userId: localStorage.getItem('userId') }).subscribe(
  response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.userDetails = JSON.parse(response);
  },
  err => {
  console.error('User Not found');
  })

}
}
```

accountService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';


@Injectable()
export class AccountService {

  public apiPath: string;//Api URL where we need to send our data & perform related operations
  constructor(ds: DataService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiPath = ds.apiPath;
}

getUser(user) {//Getting User with userId
  return this.http.post(this.apiPath + 'user/getUser', user, { responseType: 'text' });
}
}
```

UserController.js:

```
userRouter.post('/getUser', (req, res) => {
var user = {
_id: req.body.userId,
};
Collections.user.findOne(user, function (err, result) {
if (err) return res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the user");
if (result) {
res.status(200).send(result);
} else {
res.status(500).send("User Not Found with Details: " + JSON.stringify(user));
}
});
});
```

My database name is testdb and collection name is users